# Java - NoSuchMethodError not caught by Exception

Tags: java, exception, nosuchmethoderror

I was under the impression that Exception is good for catching all possible exceptions since every one of them has Exception as a base class. Then while developing an Android app I used the following method which in some custom ROMs has been removed.

```
boolean result = false;
try{
   result =  Settings.canDrawOverlays(context);
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("error","error");
}
```

However this did not catch the exception thrown. Later I used `NoSuchMethodError` instead of `Exception` and then the exception was caught.

Can someone explain why this is happening ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Java exception hierarchy looks like so:

```
Throwable
 |      |
Error   Exception
        |
        RuntimeException
```

Errors are intended for signaling regarding problems in JVM internals and other abnormal conditions which usually cannot be handled by the program anyhow. So, in your code you are not catching them. Try to catch `Throwable` instead:

```
boolean result = false;
try{
   result =  Settings.canDrawOverlays(context);
}
catch(Throwable e){
    Log.e("error","error");
}
```

Also it's a good idea to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

Comment: aaaw ok...I assumed that NoSuchMethodError was extending Exception. Thumbs up for the graphics. thank you.