# How to stop the sending email from Jenkins pipeline when cancel the job in Jenkins manually

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline using Groovy to send the status of the builds via emails when it is failure or unstable. But when i cancel the build manually in Jenkins, the email still send because it take that as a failure. How can i make Jenkins not to send emails in this situation?

Answer (score -1):

You can play with the `FlowInterruptedException`, for example, my not graceful, but working solution:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException
node(){
    stage("doing things"){
        sendEmailflag = true
        try{
            echo "into try block"
            sleep 10
        }
        catch(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {
            sendEmailflag = false
            echo "!!!caused error $e"
            throw e
        }
        finally{
            if(sendEmailflag == false)
                {echo "do not send e-mail"}
            else
                {echo "send e-mail"}
        }
    }
}
```

this is based on:

[Abort current build from pipeline in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667600/abort-current-build-from-pipeline-in-jenkins/42672345)

[How to catch manual UI cancel of job in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599268/how-to-catch-manual-ui-cancel-of-job-in-jenkinsfile)

[Catching mulitple errors in Jenkins workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188997/catching-mulitple-errors-in-jenkins-workflow)

Comment: Can't just say FlowInterruptedException without saying where that is.